# Estimating confidence intervals on count data from classifier output on varying populations

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, count-data

I have a widget factory which produces a varying number of widgets each day. Every day, I need to report the number of faulty widgets. But the proportion of faulty widgets is expected to change every day. So I cannot simply model the proportion. Instead, I have a classifier which can classify every widget as faulty or not with some error (both false-positives and false-negatives). I also have a labeled random sample of 100 widgets with known faultiness. I would like to use the classifier's performance on this sample, so that I can produce 95% confidence intervals on each day's count of faulty widgets.

How do I do this?

I considered using bootstrap on the labeled-sample of 100 to estimate a 95% confidence interval for the proportional error, PE = ActualCount / ClassifierDerivedCount. Then on a given day, I would just multiply that day's ClassifierDerivedCount by the upper and lower values of the PE confidence interval to extrapolate the 95% confidence interval of the counts. But this seems overly complicated to me, and I am distrustful of the final step. Is there an easier way?